# Trying to get my expanded list to push other elements upwards?

Tags: css, reactjs

I've built a section that will eventually become a product filter. I already have the functionality that when the parent option is clicked, the list expands to reveal the sub-options. Only problem is that I need the parent option and styled span to be pushed upwards, with the bottom of the sub-options being where the parent option and span used to sit, at the bottom of that line, if that makes sense...

React :

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import "./LeftMenuBar.js.css";

class LeftMenuBar extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        isHidden: true
        }
    }

    handleToggle(e){
        console.log(e);
        this.setState({
            isHidden: !this.state.isHidden
        })
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.isHidden);
        return (
            <div className="LeftMenu">
                <div className="filterList">
                    <ul className="ul-style">
                        <li id="filterOption"><a onClick={(e) => this.handleToggle(e)} href="#"><span className="dot"/>Option 1</a>
                            <ul className={`list ${this.state.isHidden ? 'is-hidden' : ''}`}>
                                <li className="expanded">Sub</li>
                                <li className="expanded">Sub</li>
                                <li className="expanded">Sub</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div className="filterLine">
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

export default LeftMenuBar;

And here's the CSS :

```
.LeftMenu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    z-index: 3;
}

.filterLine {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    left: 75px;
    top: 180px;
    background-color: black;
    height: 100%;
}

.LeftMenu.logo {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.filterList {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 75px;
}

#filterOption {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0;
}

#filterOption a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    padding-top: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.dot {
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
    border: 5px solid #e9e9e9;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    left: -20px;
}

.ul-style {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    top: 360px;
    width: 95px;
}

.list.is-hidden {
    display: none;
}

li a {
    color: black;
}

.expanded {
    display: block;
    left: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need the parent option and styled span to be pushed upwards, with the bottom of the sub-options being where the parent option and span used to sit.

Replace your CSS with the following to see how a few lines of flexbox can handle this:

```
.LeftMenu {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
}
.filterList {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    height: 100%;
}
.is-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Here is a demo sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/xr47k1wqlq